# Problem with Get'ting files with << as opposed to Get

Tags: import, evaluation, string-manipulation

When trying to import some files into my Mathematica notebook, I wanted to use `ToString` to specify the file path. Consider the following MWE, where we export some expression to the directory of the notebook, and immediately import it back:

```
In[1]:= Export[ToString[NotebookDirectory[]]<>"output.txt", 2020];
  import1 = Import[ToString[NotebookDirectory[]]<>"output.txt"]

Out[2]= "2020"
```

This works as expected. However, consider using `Get` and its symbolic representation `<<`:

```
In[3]:= import2 = Get[ToString[NotebookDirectory[]]<>"output.txt"] 
      << ToString[NotebookDirectory[]]<>"output.txt"

Out[3]= 2020

During evaluation of In[3]:= Get::noopen: Cannot open ToString[NotebookDirectory[]].
During evaluation of In[3]:= StringJoin::string: String expected at position 1 in $Failed<>output.txt.
Out[4]= $Failed <> "output.txt"
```

So`Get` works, but why does `<<` make `StringJoin` not recognise `ToString[NotebookDirectory[]]` as a valid `StringQ`? Am I using incorrect syntax?

---

*Additional question*: I also noticed that:

```
In[5]:= Head/@{import1, import2}

Out[5]= {String, Integer}
```

From the documentation, we read that `Import` "imports data from the source, returning a Wolfram Language representation of it", contrary to`Get`
which also evaluates the expression. Does that mean the `Import`
ed data will *always* be of the String type, regardless of the type of data I export in the first step?

Comment: 1. `NotebookDirectory` already returns a string, so there is no need for `ToString`. 2. You may want to look at [`FileNameJoin`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileNameJoin.html). 3.  The results of `Import` depends on whether the input can be interpreted and translated to a MMA expression. In most (useful) cases, it will not be a string. See the docs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I removed `ToString`; also `FileNameJoin` is certainly useful. In either case though, the problem with `Get` vs `<<` persists. I can't understand why the latter does not recognise the file path (everything until "output.txt") as a valid sting. It would be interesting to find out the reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<<` is meant to be used only with a simple name on the right, and it will interpret this name as a string.

`<< name` means `Get["name"]` and not `Get[name]`. `<< f[]` means `Get["f[]"]` and not `Get[f[]]`.

There are also issues with precedence. `<< x <> y` means `StringJoin[ Get["x"], y ]`. Try this:

```
Hold[<< x <> y] // FullForm

(* Hold[StringJoin[Get["x"],y]] *)
```

Generally, if you want to compute the file name with a function or expression, then use `Get[expr]`. If you have a literal `"filename"`, then you can use `<< filename` (no quotes needed).

You can, in principle, use the `<<` syntax with expressions. For example, `<< (f[])`, with the parentheses, is interpreted as `Get[f[]]`. But there is no point in doing this, and many people (including myself) will find it confusing.